# how to Project all columns in relational algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

do we need project sign (pi) when we dont want to filter any columns in relational algebra?

or simply if we want to get every column to be returned?

and i guess same goes with the selction operator i.e if we dont want to filter any rows.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have a table that has three columns,,, loan_num,branch_name,amount... i want to get result that has loan less than 5000 and with all the columns..

Comment: Please edit your question, comments are not for clarifications. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You use projection per columns when you want a value like another value but with only the given columns. If you don't, don't. (Although projecting on all columns outputs its input relation.)

You use selection/restriction per a condition when you want a value like another value but with only the tuples satisfying the condition. If you don't, don't. (Although selection/restriction on an always-true condition outputs its input relation.)

Relation operators are like any other operators. You use them in an expression to build the value you want out of given values.

(One of the many ways that the SQL database programming language is poorly designed is that to algebraically select/restrict (WHERE) and/or join (JOIN) you must also project (SELECT).)